# Which is correct? Your or their?

Tags: pronouns, grammatical-number, singular-they

> But if you are a teenager who criticizes **your** parents for their lack of technological awareness, don't be too hard on them.

Or

> But if you are a teenager who criticizes **their** parents for their lack of technological awareness, don't be too hard on them.

Which is correct?

I found it on [SSC Exam tutor](http://www.sscexamtutor.com/2016/09/cloze-test-asked-in-ssc-cgl-tier-2-2015.html?m=1).

I think it should be **their** since who refers to third person but I'm not sure of that.

Can you please tell me which is correct?

Comment: The first is grammatically correct.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I wouldn't be so black and white if I were you.. Actually, there's a case to be said that the second form is not wholly inappropriate, the singular "they" replacing "he or she" etc. Some writers might even prefer using "his or her" in this instance.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I can't see anything to disagree with in the statement _"The first is grammatically correct."_ Do you believe that the first sentence is not grammatically correct?

Comment: @P.E.Dant *Do you mean to say that you believe the first sentence is not grammatically correct* Did I say that it was incorrect? Where? Instead, your first comment ("The first is grammatically correct.") which presents itself as an answer, strongly suggests that the other form is *ungrammatical*. It doesn't allow any alternative.

Comment: _Your parents_ is grammatically correct. There is no such determiner as "his/her". _Their_ is acceptable, but _your_ is preferable in this instance, since it agrees in number with _you_ in the _if_ clause.

Comment: There's no need to use generic **their** since **your** is  already a kind of generic and it is already gender-neutral. That said, **their** would be used here by some native speakers, since **you** and **your** are not perfectly generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your sentences are understandable

> But if you are a teenager who criticizes **your** parents for their lack of technological awareness, don't be too hard on them.

reason is obvious.

Your second sentence

> But if you are a teenager who criticizes **their** parents for their lack of technological awareness, don't be too hard on them.

is really saying

> But if you are **one of those teenagers** who criticizes **their** parents for their lack of technological awareness, don't be too hard on them.